# constraints different moments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of schedules

So my question is this : How can I make a constraint to forbid a values to be scheduled no more than once a day. 
Thanks ahead.

Comment: create unique index (vessel, date)

Comment: Thank you @Lashane it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a unique constraint/index on the vessel and date:

```
create unique index unq_tourschedule_vesselid_tourdate on tourschedule(vesselid, tourdate);
```

(A unique constraint is implemented using a unique index.)

You should do this in the database, so even manual changes to the data enforce this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level you need to "prevent" the scheduling. Do you want to prevent it from the UI, the middle-tier, or at the database level?

- UI - Do an AJAX check against DB or middle-tier check and prevent insertion of the record there (not a secure solution, but worth mentioning because it informs your users of an existing record).
- Middle Tier - best place. Query your DB to see if a record exists with that given vesselID and TourDate. If any records are returned, do not allow insertion. You could then redirect to the page with a helpful message to the user. Business logic goes here typically, and it is best to decouple your business logic from your database.
- Database level - most robust, but least maintainable and bad practice for business logic visibility. Many options, all of them cumbersome:

Stored procedure - upon insert, check the records, same procedure as middle tier, but you have to funnel your "error" message up through all the tiers.

Compound key using vesselID and TourDate ensures automatically that only unique entries can be inserted.

Constraint on the table data upon insertion - not just an index, which is for searching optimization, but an actual constraint. This constraint may be added to an existing table or be part of the table creation statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have created a unique Index and everything worked out all right thank you for helping me out.